# How to get 'oilpaint' effect on images in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-bitmap

I am trying get oilpaint/watercolor effect to bitmap in android.[I found some algorithm problem to apply in java](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Image-Oil-Painting-and-b0977ea9)

And i can`t find documentation (without library like opencv, jhlabs) please suggest something..

Comment: Check this out : http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html it has oil paint filter

Comment: I think you can use library for such process. Otherwise try to implement what opensource filter libraries have done. [Here](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter) is such a library.

Comment: it`s advisable to use libary for single effect i does`t need more complext effect of libraries.

Comment: OpenCV has similar functions you must try it out. You can perform **cartooning** and **pencil sketching** as well. They are bunch of direct/in-built functions